# swift getting data for selected cell in another ViewController (programatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This question has been answered many times. But the answers I could find on it, didn't work for me, cause I can't seem to call the cell's class.

to further explain:

I have a viewController, with a UITable. The cells are configured in a UITableViewCell class. (it's from this class I need to pull the information)

my "cell class" is called mySuggestionsCel

Here's my code for "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.allowsSelection = false

    var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    var VC = detaiLSuggestion_VC()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)


    if selectedCell.backgroundColor == UIColor.formulaFormColor() {
        selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaMediumBlue()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaFormColor()
        })
    } else {
        selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaLightGreenColor()
        })
    }
}
```

I tried doing

mySuggestionsCell.someVariable

I also tried selectedCell.someVariable

neither worked.

I need to get this information from my detailSuggestion_VC(), from my cell Class. But the data it needs to pull, is the data the specific cell that's getting selected has. Which is why I'm having some trouble getting this to work.

I looked around for a while. But couldn't find any questions or answers to this specific issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "neither worked"? You need to be specific. What happens when you try to access someVariable, and what variable are you talking about? Why are you typing selectedCell to UITableViewCell instead of mySuggestiosCell?

Comment: #rdelmar, It does comes with the error "UITableViewCell does not have a member called 'ticker', same with the other one except it's "mySuggestionsCell" of course. (but that one wouldn't have worked anyway), anyhow. I'm trying to access data for a cell, set in a tableViewCell class, to pass to another viewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making the following assumptions:

1. You have a tableViewCell class file that controls your table cells.
2. You have a detail-view controller that your table segues to when you tap a cell.
3. What you want to do is to pass the tapped cell's information so your new view controller has all the cell's info.

Instead of this:
`var selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!`

You will need to instead do a typecast into your tableViewCell class. Like so:

`var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as tableViewCell`

What you need to do next is to call the following function:

`performSegueWithIdentifier(/*Segue Identifier goes here*/, sender: selectedCell)`

Making this call will pass selectedCell's contents into sender, which can be used in `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject)`

make sure you override prepareForSegue somewhere in your class.

Now, in prepareForSegue:, you can get a reference to the destinationViewController, and initialize the instance variable in the destinationViewController that will hold your selectedCell's variables.

```
//in prepareForSegue
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as detailSuggestion_VC
controller.cellInfo = sender
```

Comment: hey Kelvin, thanks for the reply!, Though I think it's not what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain it a bit better. I'm dealing with 1 viewController called "mySuggestions_VC", that has a tableview (with cells), these are very custom cells. So to configure them, and get their data. I use a tableViewCell class, in another file. (<- that's the file That has the data). Now, when I tap on any of the cells, it goes to another viewController called "detailSuggestion_VC", in this viewcontroller, I need a lot of the information from my cell class. but I can't find any way to call it.

Comment: @user10002

Ok, thanks for explaining. I know one way to do that, but you'll still need to typecast your UITableViewCell to your new tableViewCell class (that you created specifically for your custom cell. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update! however I'm still having some issues: "ar selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as tableViewCell" causes an error: "Use of undeclared type 'tableViewCell' "

Also, I'm doing everything programatically, so I can't use segues, and thus don't have access to "prepareForSegue" to put data in. Any ideas?

Comment: tableViewCell is the name of your custom UITableViewCell class. Whatever you named that file to be. 

This is the main problem that's preventing you from referencing your cell's properties.